# Runtime error 5 because variable comes up as nothing when it shouldn't

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to fix a inventory log for my work that has been around for years and has always had this bug. The script is supposed to look at a provided tag number, figure out if it has been returned or not and then mark the item as returned if the name matches. For tag numbers 1501 through 2040 it works perfectly fine, however once you attempt to search tag numbers 2041 to 2300 it will immediately throw a Code 5 error and crash the script. Debug says the range = nothing

here is the main code:

```
Dim AmbRng As Range
Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
TheDate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")
TheTime = Format(Time, "Medium Time")
findstring = ByItemNumberTextBox.Value
If Trim(findstring) <> "" And Trim(findstring) >= 1501 And Trim(findstring) <= 2300 Then
    With Sheets("AmbBay").Range("AmbBay_Ticket_Numbers")
        Set AmbRng = .Find(What:=findstring, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
            Application.Goto AmbRng, True
```

The debug always points to the last line and says AmbRng = nothing. I presume this is an integer overflow but I haven't been able to find a workaround through google or here. My VBA skills are rudimentary and self taught, so I assume I am missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If `AmbRng` is `Nothing`, that means that the `Find` did not succeed (not related to an overflow error).

Comment: hmm then I am even more confused because what would make the difference between a single number? if works perfectly up to once number in the range 2040, then stops functioning immediately afterword. Code further down has it display a VB message box if there is no issued tag and it works for 2040 but fails starting at 2041.

Comment: Are these numbers formulaically generated or what? Can you find them manually using Ctrl+F?

Comment: Yes they an be found control+f they are in the a column cells from row 9 to row 808. They are pre-existing before the script runs.

Comment: If you are only looking in one column, you could use `Application.Match` instead of `Range.Find`.

Comment: Have you tried `.Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)`. I usually use  `.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)`.

Comment: You might have some 'invisible' character or a space with the numbers from 2041 to 2300. In Excel use the `CODE` function: `=CODE(LEFT(A1,1))` and `=CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))`.

Comment: Changing it to cells.CountLarge doesn't seem to affect anything. using .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) doesn't seem to affect anything either. The script works up to 2040 with both but once again breaks at 2041.

Comment: Your `Named Range, "AmbBay_Ticket_Numbers"` is only select for `("A9:A548")`

Comment: @GMalc named range is my guess too.  roeboat72 open the name manager in the Formulas ribbon and verify the named range actually covers all your data.

Comment: @ionizing i tested and it is the problem.

Comment: That worked thank you so much! Sorry I am still pretty new at VBA so I appreciate the help so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMalc answered the question in the comments, I appreciate everyone's help.